# Delphi XE5 Android Thread makes app crash

Tags: android, multithreading, delphi, delphi-xe5

I have a thread downloading and saving a clientDataset file cds file from a remote Datasnap Server.

This thread works in Windows, IOS (Simulator, Iphone, Ipad) but not on Android.

The app crashes after completed the file download and save it on Android.

The code is simple.

Thread:

```
TDownloadSaveRemoteDBThread = class (TThread)
public
  Username,Password,host,port : String;
  error                      : String;
  Folder                     : String;
  ServerMethod               : String;
  filename                   : String;
protected
  procedure Execute; override;
end;

procedure TDownloadSaveRemoteDBThread.Execute;
var
  sqlCon : TSqlConnection;
  cds    : TClientDataset;
  ssm    : TSqlServerMethod;
  dpr    : TDataSetProvider;
begin
  inherited;

  error :='';
  SqlCon:=TSQLConnection.Create(nil);
  try
    sqlCon.DriverName:='Datasnap';
    sqlCon.LoginPrompt:=false;
    sqlCon.Params.Values['hostname']:=host;
    sqlCon.Params.Values['port']:=port;
    sqlCon.Params.Values['UserName']:=Username;
    sqlCon.Params.Values['Password']:=Password;
    try
      sqlCon.Open;
      cds:=TClientDataset.Create(nil);
      ssm:=TSqlServerMethod.Create(nil);
      dpr:=TDataSetProvider.Create(nil);
      try
        ssm.SQLConnection:=SqlCon;
        ssm.ServerMethodName:=ServerMethod;
        dpr.DataSet:=ssm;
        cds.SetProvider(dpr);
        cds.Open;
        cds.SaveToFile(folder+filename);
        cds.Close;
      finally
        cds.free;
        ssm.free;
        dpr.free;
      end;
    Except
      on E : Exception do
      Begin
        error:=E.Message;
        SQLCon.Close;
      End;
    end;
  finally
    SQLCon.Close;
    SQLCon.free;
  end;
end;
```

I have a button to start the thread in my mainform “Start Form”

```
procedure TStartForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  DownloadSaveRemoteDBThread : TDownloadSaveRemoteDBThread;
begin
  DownloadSaveRemoteDBThread:= TDownloadSaveRemoteDBThread.Create(true);
  DownloadSaveRemoteDBThread.OnTerminate:= StartForm.ferdigHentDB;
  DownloadSaveRemoteDBThread.Password:='test';
  DownloadSaveRemoteDBThread.Username:='test';
  DownloadSaveRemoteDBThread.host:=edit1.text; //127.0.0.1
  DownloadSaveRemoteDBThread.port:='211';
  DownloadSaveRemoteDBThread.Folder:=System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath +  PathDelim +'db'+  PathDelim;
  DownloadSaveRemoteDBThread.ServerMethod:= 'TServerMethods2.hentselect3';
  DownloadSaveRemoteDBThread.filename:='select3.cds';
  DownloadSaveRemoteDBThread.FreeOnTerminate:=true;
  DownloadSaveRemoteDBThread.Start;
end;
```

Then after thread is finished I have this simple procedure

```
procedure TStartForm.ferdigHentDB(sender: Tobject);
begin

  with sender as TDownloadSaveRemoteDBThread do
  Begin
    if error > '' then
    Begin
      showmessage(error);
    End;
  End;
end;
```

Any suggestions why Android crashes, is there an easy fix for this issue?

Comment: Did you check in the documentation of the database driver if the android version supports multithreaded connections?

Answer (score 2):

`TThread` in XE5 has two major bugs on Android.  `Sychronize()` and `Queue()` are broken (`Synchronize()` is used to trigger the `OnTerminate` event), and `TThread` does not detach itself from the Android JVM before termination if any JNI objects are used by the thread. [The first bug](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=123579) has not been fixed yet.  The second bug is fixed in XE6, but there is [a workaround](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=93533) you can use in XE5.

Comment: Thank you, but I can figure out how to implement the fix. procedure 

`MyEndThreadProc(ExitCode:Integer);
`   
in my system.classes I find this code 
` {$ELSEIF Defined(POSIX)}
    if Assigned(EndThreadProc) then
      EndThreadProc(Result);
    pthread_exit(Result);
{$ENDIF POSIX}`  

Does anyone have an example how to assign MyEndThreadProc in system.classes

Comment: What was unclear in the link I posted? It tells you *exactly* how to implement the fix. `EndThreadProc` is a function pointer. Simply copy the provided function into your code and then assign its address to the `System.Classes.EndThreadProc` variable at app startup.  `TThread` will then call your function whenever a `TThread`-based thread terminates.